# Ошибка datepicker и laravel 5.8

Tags: jquery, laravel, datepicker

Привет пример реализации брал от сюда: [Пример реализации](https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=4&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox)
У меня в blade выглядит код вот так:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <link id="bs-css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
            });
        })
    </script>
```

При обновлении страницы выдает консоль ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Так же пытался повторить пример: [Пример с codepen](https://codepen.io/saifur0123/pen/KZEaeR)
Такая же ошибка, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Гуглить пробовали? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207203/uncaught-typeerror-datepicker-is-not-a-functionanonymous-function

Comment: Пробовал как раз этот ответ тоже не подошел